# Vim - Problem mapping keys in command mode

Tags: vim

To make it easier to edit my `~/.vimrc` file, I set up the following:

```
:cnoremap ev :<C-u>vsplit $MYVIMRC<cr>
```

So, to open `~/.vimrc` in a split I just enter command mode and enter `ev`. However, I would like do the same thing entering `ev` and then `<Enter>` (just like the other default commands), so I tried this:

```
:cnoremap ev<cr> :<C-u>vsplit $MYVIMRC<cr>
```

This gives `E492: Not an editor command: ev`.
Why is this?

Comment: Both mappings work for me as designed.

Comment: BTW if you want to enter something at the command line why not create a function and/or a command? `command! Ev vsplit $MYVIMRC`. The only disadvantage is that user-defined function/command names must start with an uppercase letter.

Comment: This is weird. On top of that, I added the mapping ```:cnoremap sv<cr> :<C-u>source $MYVIMRC<cr>``` and when I type ```:sv<Enter>``` it just opens up the same file I'm in in a new split.

Comment: Duplicate of https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/22740/18609